# how to change color of textview hyperlink?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this code for hyperlink:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/hyperlink" 
    android:text="@string/hyperlink"
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

By default it is showing blue color, but how do I change color of hyperlink in Android?

Answer (score 788, accepted):

Add `android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere"` to your `TextView`

Comment: this worked thanks `android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"`

Comment: I display the link as the title on a `Button` which inherits from `android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small`? How can I change the text color of the link when the button is pressed?

Comment: Was searching for a simple answer and kept on looking at the Spannable class.. thank you so much for this simple answer!

Answer (score 54):

If you want to change it programmatically:

```
yourText.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use on your XML file:

```
android:textColorLink="Code"
```

the "Code" can be e.g. `#ff0000` or @color/red

You can use on your JAVA code :

```
tv.setLinkTextColor(color);
```

The color can be e.g `Color.RED` or `Color.parseColor("#ff0000");`

Answer (score 16):

Add these Lines of code to your `textview` in `XML` file and it will work perfectly fine

```
android:autoLink="web"
 android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
 android:linksClickable="true"
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the `android:textColorLink="#000000"` where `000000` is your color's hex code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can also open colors.xml and change the following color to whatever you want:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone needs to know the hex value for this blue it is #7bc9c2.

I used Eye Dropper to figure this out as I couldn't find it documented anywhere, it isn't on the Google Color Palatte anyway:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Answer (score 3):

You need to use  `android:textColorLink="colorCode"` . Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

In xml file of `TextView` tag :

```
android:autoLink="web" //link the content of web  
android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" //change the color of the link
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the link color in your theme using android:textColorLink. You probably need to set both light and dark theme when you do that

Answer (score 0):

My **Compose** hyperlink changed color

```
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red)) { // your color
        append("Link Text")
        addStringAnnotation(
            tag = "URL",
            annotation = "https://www.example.com",
            start = 0,
            end = "Link Text".length
        )
    }
}

ClickableText(
    text = annotatedString,
    onClick = { offset ->
        annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(tag = "URL", start = offset, end = offset)
            .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
              // link click action code             }
    }
)
```