# Html.fromHtml() is not able to decode font color for anchor attribute

Tags: android, html

I am trying to set simple html content to a textview, content is something like:

```
Click <a href="any_link" target="_blank"><font color="#0000ff"><u>here</u></font></a> for details.
```

Setting this simply using Html.fromHtml() results this:

[image]

Ideally, the link color should be **blue(#0000ff)** but it is showing in the default platform link color.

When I removed **href tag** from  the result was expected:

[image]

I could not understand why android is not able to handle color when href is present inside  tag.

***I have previewed the HTML content in a web browser, it is working as expected, also I have tested the same HTML content on the iOS platform it is working as expected.***

I have tried using all the available Html flag options but no luck.(tested in simulator and device as well).

I could not use `textColorLink` as there are multiple links with different colors in actual HTML content.

```
val htmlContent = "Click <a target=\"_blank\"><font color=\"#0000ff\"><u>here</u></font></a> for details."
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.text = Html.fromHtml(htmlContent, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }
```

Please help me to understand if there is any flaw in my code or there is limitations/bug in android.

Comment: By any chance, isn't that color the primary color of your app's theme?

Comment: @Wang oh yes it's picking a color from the theme, it's using colorAccent by default.

Comment: Ok, I put that as an answer so that people who read this later can quickly spot the solution ;)

Comment: @Wang Okay, but this does not solve anything, the issue is the font color which should be picked from HTML content, not the default ascent color. Any clue?

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763393/3692518

Comment: No @Wang can't use textColorLink because it will set the same color to all the links present in HTML content, that's what my concern is, I have to keep it dynamic relying on the font color defined in HTML.